# Dart library / package keyword meaning?

Tags: dart

Is **Dart library** exactly the same **Java package** ?

Is **Dart package** exactly the same **Java library** (JAR) ?

Comment: Two files can not have the same library name, that is very different from Java packages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A package is a set of libraries which can for example be deployed to pub.dartlang.org. I guess this is similar to a jar file.
A library is one Dart script file with or without a name (or a set of Dart script files with `part`/`part of`) and is the boundary for privacy. Private members are only visible or accessible from within the same library.

Comment: Ok, I think the word **library** has another meaning in software development but that would be another discussion. It would be more appropriate **namespace**.

Comment: You are **SO** right, tenés la posta, hermano... Why on hell library instead of namespace?!?!? >.<

Comment: It just isn't a namespace.