# Reducing amount of 'parts' in a Dart app

Tags: dart

I have a rather large Dart application that uses `part` and `part of` so that I don't have to use relative `import`s. However, the application may have something like this at the entry point file:

```dart
part 'file1.dart';
part 'file2.dart';
part 'file3.dart';
part 'some_sub_dir/file1.dart';
part 'some_sub_dir/file2.dart';
part 'some_sub_dir/file3.dart';
part 'some_sub_dir/file4.dart';
part 'some_sub_dir/file5.dart';
part 'some_sub_dir/file6.dart';
...
```

As far as I know, my IDE (WebStorm) doesn't automatically add a `part` statement when I create a new class. Is there any way I can avoid having to use so many `part`s? If not, can the process of adding new `parts` each time be automated?

Comment: You can put all code in one file. It's not entirely clear to me what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your problem as I can and I'll try to answer from my experience in Dart.

As I got it you are trying to keep all (or a lot) project files as parts of one library. It's wrong conception. In Dart library is not big thing. Here is few advices how to organize your files.

1. Don't try to keep a lot of files as parts of one library. Rather keep each file as separated library.
2. You can keep few classes in one file. But be sure classes works together for one idea.
3. You can split one library in few part files only if it has a lot of classes or one class is too big. But be sure all this files should be together in one library.
4. If you don't know how to combine classes in libraries keep each class in separated library. After days you will get understanding which classes plays together.
5. If one class from one library has usages in not only library but in other libraries - make it separated library.
6. Place parts in same folder with main library file.
7. If library has parts put all library files into separated folder.
8. Use relative links to parts.
9. Always use absolute links to other libraries. It will help you to make refactoring in future.

For example, this is a project like TODO list application. So, we have view class:

```
// This is a view html component class. //
library todolist.list_viewer;

import 'package:todolist/task.dart'; // model class

class ListViewer extends HtmlElement {
  // it showes list of tasks
}

class TodoRenderer extends HtmlElement {
  // this is a renderer for one todo item
}
```

And this is a model class:

```
// This is a todo model task //
library todolist.task;

class TodoProvider {
  List<TodoItem> todos;
  String addItem(TodoItem new Todo) { 
    //... 
  }
}

class TodoItem {
  String Author;
  DateTime date;
}
```

It looks simple now, divided into separated libraries. But if we want to add `RecId` class to keep todo database id it becomes too complex. We should split it in two libraries: `todo_provider` and `todo_model` and put `RecId` class into last one. Now it's good again.

If we wanna add one more model: a `User`, so each todo item may have executor or author. We can't just put it `todo_model`. Now we should to combine `TodoItem` and `User` classes into `model` library. So we just rename `todo_model` class to `model` and add `User` class into it.

Or instead last action we can make `user_model` library to keep `User` class. And as User model has `recId` property too we should extract `RecId` class into separated library.

It's all depends on how our classes big and complex.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that:

**part/part of** is used to break a library into several parts (scripts). You have visibility to public and private members.

**import** is to "call/use" another library from your library. You have only visibility to public members of the imported library.

WebStorm can't infer you want a script to be part of your library.

Comment: @bionicrm, view my question. [Dart library / package keyword meaning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736890/dart-library-package-keyword-meaning)

Comment: It would be good to "WebStorm" autocomplete the "part of" counterpart